# Benefits from using akka dispatcher vs scala global

Tags: scala, concurrency, akka

Couldn't find any info on this. I have a Akka/Spray based service and was always using `ExecutionContext.global` if i wanted to write some async code with std scala Future. Are there any benefits from using a dispatcher in akka based app rather than importing a global one? And also are there are any disadvantages from mixing (some parts are using akka's dispatcher and other parts scale's global)?

Comment: Slavic party over here, by the way :-)

Answer (score 6):

Don't use Akka default Dispatcher for execution of blocking calls in Future-s - in this case you can get all your Actors sitting on the default Dispatcher fully hanged in case of all threads of the default Dispatcher are blocked by blocking calls in such Future-s.

Usage of different Dispatcher-s for different Actor types (and especially for Future-s that do blocking calls) is known as Bulkhead Pattern.

ExecutionContext.global is a ForkJoinPool (by default) that use scala.concurrent.context.minThreads/maxThreads/numThreads settings for configure number of threads. So, IMHO, you can use it for Future-s execution instead of any other Akka Dispatcher with fork-join-executor.

But I would suggest to use a separate Akka Dispatcher for bulkheading just to have all Dispatchers configured in a single place (in Akka config).

Comment: Actually i was interested in a bit different thing. When i'm using futures inside Akka Actor, what are the different between executing futures with Scala global ctx vs importing context.dispatcher and are there any?

Comment: AFAIK no difference (of course if they are ForkJoinPool-s by default). Except possible blocking of all threads in context.dispatcher by Futures (which can hang your Actors).